# SQL Statement to show columns multiple times

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table containing an integer column that represents a work place, an integer column that represents the number of workpieces finished at that workplace and a date column.
I want to create a query that creates rows of the following type

```
location int | date of Max(workpiece) | max workpieces | Min(Date) | workpieces (Min(Date)) | max(Date) | workpieces (Max(Date))
```

So i want a row for each location containing the date of the day where the most pieces where finished plus the amount of the pieces, the oldest date and the pieces finished on that day and the newest date plus the number of pieces finished that day.

Do I have to use joins, to join the table with itself 3 times each given one of the criteria and then join on location? Is The GROUP BY Operator involved, which I don't quite get the hang of?

EDIT: Here's some sample data

`+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   id  | location  |   amount  |       date        |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   1   |   1       |     10    |   01.01.2016      |
|   2   |   2       |     5     |   01.01.2016      |
|   3   |   1       |     6     |   02.01.2016      |
|   4   |   2       |     35    |   02.01.2016      |
|   5   |   1       |     50    |   03.01.2016      |
|   6   |   2       |     20    |   03.01.2016      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+`

I want my output to look like this:

`loc | dateMaxAmount| MaxAmount | MinDate   | AmountMinDate | MaxDate   | MaxDateAmount
1    | 03.01.2016   | 50        | 01.01.2016| 10            | 03.01.2016| 50
2    | 02.01.2016   | 35        | 01.01.2016| 5             | 03.01.2016| 20`

I am using MS Access.

Comment: MySQL and ms access are two different products with different features and functions. Which one do you use? Pls add sample data and expected output on sample data to the question along with a sample query of what you have tried. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for further details on how to ask a good sql related question.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description. Note: Sample data != real data.

Comment: At a first glance your fields # 2 and 3 seem to represent the same as field # 6 and 7. Try to word them better. Instead of MaxDate use MostRecentDate.